python regualr expression (re.search) ipv4 address format
I am doing CS50P online.
The question asked us to validate IP address in IPv4 format.
My code is:

def main():
    ip = input("IPv4 Address: ")

    if validate(ip):
        print(validate(ip))
    else:
        print(validate(ip))

def validate(ip):
    pattern = r"^(0|[1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-5][0-5]?)\.(0|[1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-5][0-5]?)\.(0|[1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-5][0-5]?)\.(0|[1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-5][0-5]?)$"
    match = re.search(pattern, ip)
    if match:
        return True
    else:
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()`


My question is: I dont understand why this will return False for 140.247.235.144?
I later amended it to

def main():
    ip = input("IPv4 Address: ")

    if validate(ip):
        print(validate(ip))
    else:
        print(validate(ip))

def validate(ip):
    pattern = r"^(0|[1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(0|[1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(0|[1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(0|[1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$"
    match = re.search(pattern, ip)
    if match:
        return True
    else:
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


It now works just fine. Can someone explain please? Also, how can I tighten it up with the constraint of only REGEX is allowed?

Why with regex and not algorithm?

This question is similar to: check if a string matches an IP address pattern in python?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In the first variant the 2[0-5][0-5] part can't match247 because 7 is greater than 5.

Instead of your if/else, just call the validating function and print what it returns.

It does not accept the range 246-249 because 2[0-5][0-5]? this expression does not allow it. Since the [0-5]? condition does not satisfy values ​​greater than 5, 140.247.235.144 does not accept the expression 247 here.
You can prevent your second statement from being repeated by grouping.
^((0|[1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(0|[1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$


Thank you so much! This explained everything!

You're welcome, I'm glad to help. It will help others if you approve the answer.
